# AX 2012 GL custom SSRS reports dont filter current extension (dataareaid)

Tags: reporting-services, axapta

i am facing a weird issue in AX 2012 R3 General Ledger reports (only the customized ones), 
in all reports i created from scratch either query or DP based, which read from GL tables that don't save data per company (shared tables) such as **GeneralJournalEntry** ..., these reports retrieve all companies (legal entities) data, and don't filter by the current extension,
unlike the GL standard reports such as Trial Balance.
do you have any helpful ideas to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got it,
in the DP class, a similar code of the following must be added to the query object to have a range on the field GeneralJournalEntry.ledger to be equal ledger::current
as follows:

```
ds = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(GeneralJournalEntry));
range = SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(ds, fieldNum(GeneralJournalEntry, Ledger));
range.value(SysQuery::value(Ledger::current()));
```

i hope this will be helpful to someone sometime.